# How to resolve unexpected runtime error in colab Fashion MINIST?

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error

Copying the Colab "Fashion MINIST" at udcity.com step by step.
All codes compiles and runs correctly until statement

> model.compile(optimizer='adam',
>                loss='sparce_categorical_crossentrophy', 
>                metrics=['accuracy'])

which returns

> ValueError: Unknown loss function:sparce_categorical_crossentrophy

I am at a loss as how to troubleshoot this error.  I would welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a spelling error.

```
# model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparce_categorical_crossentrophy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```